# Nginx disable https redirect for 404+http uri

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress, vestacp

I have HTTPS redirect in nginx.conf

1. But if the requested URI is HTTP and 404 - I don't need a redirect.
   Is there any solution for this specific configuration?
2. Also is there a possibility to turn off HTTPS + www redirect for 404 links like http://www.test.com
3. If point 1 or 2 cannot be done, can I hardcode a list of 404 URLs with nginx to completely turn off any redirect for them and only show 404 page? (HTTPS and www)

WordPress + Nginx (+Vestacp)

```
server {
    listen      x.x.x.x:80;
    server_name test.com www.test.com;
    root        /home/admin/web/test.com/web/;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/test.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/test.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/test.com.error.log error;
    return 301 https://test.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: It could be done for static content. For dynamic app, such as WordPress, it may not be possible. What app or kind of app do you run on this specific case? Static or dynamic?

Comment: Wordpress + Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ServerFault.

> But if the requested URI is HTTP and 404 - I don't need a redirect. Is
> there any solution for this specific configuration?

I don't know how to do this. I am unsure if it is even possible.

> Also is there a possibility to turn off HTTPS + www redirect for 404
> links like http://www.test.com

I don't understand this question.

> If point 1 or 2 cannot be done, can I hardcode a list of 404 URLs with
> nginx to completely turn off any redirect for them and only show 404
> page? (HTTPS and www)

This is possible. Assuming we have the list of files at `/home/admin/web/test.com/web/404.conf` in the following format...

```
/aboutt-us/ 404;
/about-uss/ 404;
/contactt-us/ 404;
/contact-uss/ 404;
```

Instead of the text "404", we could have anything except "0" (zero).

The modified configuration would look like this...

```
map $uri $allwillburnn { include /home/admin/web/test.com/web/404.conf; }

server {
    listen      x.x.x.x:80;
    server_name test.com www.test.com;
    root        /home/admin/web/test.com/web/;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/test.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/test.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/test.com.error.log error;
    if ( $allwillburnn ) { return 404; }
    return 301 https://test.com$request_uri;
}
```

Explanation: By default, for any URLs not listed in the aforementioned `404.conf` file, the variable named `$allwillburnn` is assigned to a value of 0 (zero) by [map](https://nginx.org/r/map). In this case, [if](https://nginx.org/r/if) block is skipped, resulting in 301 redirect.

For URLs listed in `404.conf` file, `$allwillburnn` is assigned to non-zero value. In this case, if block is parsed, resulting in 404.

I hope that helps.